# How to get multiple values using XPath?

Tags: xpath

I am using XPath to get the values from the following xml document.

```
<Const>
      <MemberLeader>xyz/MemberLeader>
      <FirstRunnerUp>txz</FirstRunnerUp>
      <SecondRunnerUp>abc</SecondRunnerUp>
      <PartyWinner>AAP</PartyWinner>
      <PartyRunnerUp>BJP</PartyRunnerUp>
      <PartySecondRunnerUp>Congress</PartySecondRunnerUp>
      <VotesWinner>4565</VotesWinner>
      <VotesFirstRunnerUp>4362</VotesFirstRunnerUp>
      <VotesSecondRunnerUp>6652</VotesSecondRunnerUp>
</Const>
```

I am using this XPath

```
/const/VotesWinner
```

My problem is that to get multiple values I have to send my query many times, again and again.

Is it possible for me to retrieve three values like VotesWinner, VotesFirstRunnerUp, VotesSecondRunnerUp with one XPath string with a comma inserted between the values for separation?

Comment: Removed my comment due to posting it as an answer.

Comment: @sumitkang Please makre sure to use proper formatting for your question. This includes using big headlines in very, very few circumstances. Otherwise, it makes my eyes hurt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **[Union](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-union)** operator '`|`' to select all three and then perform some post-processing.

Something like:

```
/const/VotesWinner|/const/VotesFirstRunnerUp|/const/VotesSecondRunnerUp
```

And then intersperse the returned list with commas.

*[converted from comment to answer.]*